# what is the meaning of "'water a horse" and "to milk the cat" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading a book now, and one of the chapters opens itself by the following phrase, which its meaning makes me to feel lost in English... even after I've done a nice research on Google and dictionaries.

> "mother, asked Kate, "Is it correct to say '**[water a horse](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=water%20the%20horse)**' when he is thirsty?"
>
> "Yes, dear, quite correct"."
>
> "Then I am going to **[milk the cat](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Milk%20the%20Cat)**"

I think that I do understand what these idioms mean (to urinate, and [getting pussy](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Getting%20Pussy)) but I don't understand them in the context at all.

For me, the question if it's "correct to say 'water a gorse' when he is thirsty" is not logical. The same thing regarding to the following comments there, there is not coherence. Therefore I would like to know the explanation for this paragraph.

[image]

and this is the full picture of the page in which these paragraph are found:

[image]

Comment: These are **jokes**, not serious propositions. The first joke exploits the fact that to *water* a horse means to provide it with water; Kate logically but erroneously assumes that she can can therefore use *milk* to speak of providing a cat with milk. The second joke exploits the spelling of *elephant* to put forward a preposterous understanding of *elephants* as a sort of *ants*.

Comment: hahahaha now I got it! thank you:) I would like to choose your answer as the accepted answer but it's comment rather than answer. I've read the answer of Colin and I didn't understand but now after your concise explanation I understand it well.

Comment: Always start with a _real_ dictionary. The "Urban Dictionary" is _not_ a useful research tool except in rare circumstances. Most dictionaries include this meaning, e.g. [**Collins**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/water): **"25. (transitive) to irrigate or provide with water ⇒ _to water the land_, ⇒ _he watered the cattle_."**

Comment: I do it as well as I did it in this case, but no results except of urban dictionary. I didn't look for water meanings but I looked for the phrase meaning 'water a horse' as it appears in the book. In this way you'll not find it in the dictionary that you mentioned and I couldn't have any clue about the meaning, again, as a non native English speaker.

Comment: In any such situation, always look for the simple answer first. Remember, dictionaries are references for words, not phrases. Always look up the individual words first. A good reference to remember is [**OneLook.**](http://www.onelook.com/?w=water&ls=a) Note the definitions under _verb._ If you had tried that first, you might have solved this problem on your own, and that is obviously the best outcome for any student. If you get in the habit of doing it this way, your English will improve quickly!

Comment: You should not rely on Urban Dictionary for the meaning of "to water" and "to milk", the entries which you linked to are **slang** and extremely vulgar. In addition, they are not even highly rated, only 17 positive votes against 12 negative for "water *the* horse". Moreover, it's clear from the next story in the image, see the pun "Eleph-ants", you  are in fact reading a joke book. Something which you conveniently omitted from saying.

Comment: It is not a joke book at all. It's English learning book (named "Tests in English" by Mariusz Misztal. The paragraph that I cited is just a opening of one of the chapters which contains a lot of questions and homework in English.

Comment: Why is it that so many learners say "in a book" but never give its title. What's so difficult about naming the source? A "book". Does it mean it *must* be about grammar? No. It could be a story, a novel, something you read online, the "book" might have been written by an Indian English speaker, or an American speaker. It might be a collection of different stories, the "book" could be about anything. But you think in an English language book they're going to use that type of slang? They're going to be teaching students of all ages about "pussies" and "pissing"?

Answer (score 9):

Im afraid you are misunderstanding the joke. It is nothing about either urinating or pussy.

One of the meanings of "water" is "give water to" - this is in common use for plants ("Water the roses" or "water the garden"). It used also to be usual for horses - I suspect that it is only not common because not many people nowadays encounter horses in their daily lives.

"Milk" as a verb, however, only means "get milk from the teats of" - most often used of cows, and sometimes other animals. (It also has a transferred meaning of "get as much value from as you can", but that is not relevant here).

So the joke is simply the girl noticing an inconsistency in how we use these verbs - 'water' meaning "give water to", and 'milk' meaning "get milk from", and mischevously extending the meaning of one to the meaning of the other.

Comment: After I've read the comment of Stoney I understood what you said:) Thank you for the answer

Comment: @Assiduous , much of English humor relates to misunderstanding that comes with the misuse of common grammar.  As another example, [Punctuation saves lives](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/de/9d/69/de9d692fdd995062a6233f19b64544bd.jpg)

Comment: Yes, I've got it.:)